# Webpack loader and compilation hash

Tags: webpack

How to access webpack compilation hash inside a loader? There is a `_compilation` property on `this` inside a loader function but the hash isn't there.

Comment: What is it that your trying to achieve? Maybe there's a way without accessing the hash directly

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Webpack Plugin API documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html), it appears that you have access to `before-hash` and `after-hash` event callbacks for the Compilation instance. To access the compilation instance you have to creat a callback to the compiler event (both examples can be found on aforementioned documentation). This should give you access to your chucks before and after they are hashed.

So you may be looking into writing a Plugin instead of a Loader.